# How to combine multiple images and multiple audio files into one video with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two images `image1.png` and `image2.png`, they both have the same dimensions. I also have two audio files `audio1.wav` and `audio2.wav` they each have **different** lengths. I want to make a video that shows `image1.png` during `audio1.wav` and then `image2.png` over `audio2.wav`.

I've tried two methods, but they don't work. The images show correctly, but the durations are not synced with the audio.

### Method 1: create videos separately and combine them:

#### image1 => video1

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 \
  -y \
  -i "image1.png" \
  -i "audio1.wav" \
  -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p \
  -c:a aac -b:a 192k \
  -shortest \
  "video1.mp4"

ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.2.0/include/openjpeg-2.2 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'image1.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 800x800, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, wav, from 'audio1.wav':
  Metadata:
    title           : untitled
    track           : 1
  Duration: 00:00:03.70, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] 264 - core 148 r2795 aaa9aa8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:-3:-3 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=2.00:0.70 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-4 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.20
Output #0, mp4, to 'video1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(progressive), 800x800, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 aac
frame=  151 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     106kB time=00:00:05.92 bitrate= 146.6kbits/s speed=6.73x
video:13kB audio:87kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 5.016360%
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] frame I:1     Avg QP:14.87  size:  5746
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] frame P:38    Avg QP:12.15  size:    51
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] frame B:112   Avg QP:16.81  size:    48
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] consecutive B-frames:  0.7%  1.3%  0.0% 98.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] mb I  I16..4: 46.9% 44.7%  8.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.7%  L0:63.5% L1:36.5% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] 8x8 transform intra:40.7% inter:20.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 4.9% 0.0% 0.0% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 82% 13%  4%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 74%  2% 24%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 33% 24% 32%  2%  2%  2%  2%  1%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 100%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] ref B L0: 48.0% 52.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] ref B L1: 99.5%  0.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fead980bc00] kb/s:17.36
[aac @ 0x7fead981b400] Qavg: 535.938
```

#### image2 => video2

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 \
  -y \
  -i "image2.png" \
  -i "audio2.wav" \
  -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p \
  -c:a aac -b:a 192k \
  -shortest \
  "video2.mp4"

ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.2.0/include/openjpeg-2.2 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'image2.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 800x800, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, wav, from 'audio2.wav':
  Metadata:
    title           : untitled
    track           : 2
  Duration: 00:00:05.49, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] 264 - core 148 r2795 aaa9aa8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:-3:-3 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=2.00:0.70 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-4 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.20
Output #0, mp4, to 'video2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(progressive), 800x800, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 aac
frame=  195 fps=177 q=-1.0 Lsize=     150kB time=00:00:07.68 bitrate= 160.2kbits/s speed=6.96x
video:14kB audio:129kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 4.516541%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] frame I:1     Avg QP: 9.03  size:  6402
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] frame P:49    Avg QP: 6.59  size:    41
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] frame B:145   Avg QP: 9.67  size:    39
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] consecutive B-frames:  0.5%  1.0%  0.0% 98.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] mb I  I16..4: 54.7% 36.0%  9.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:100.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.8%  L0:70.1% L1:29.9% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] 8x8 transform intra:36.0% inter:14.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 4.3% 0.0% 0.0% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 91%  5%  4%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 72%  8% 20%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 36% 23% 25%  4%  3%  3%  3%  2%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 100%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] ref P L0: 83.3%  8.3%  8.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] ref B L0: 40.1% 59.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa0e201ce00] kb/s:14.38
[aac @ 0x7fa0e201e600] Qavg: 595.040
```

When I import these into Final Cut I can see that both videos get around 2:30 seconds of added silence (not present in the audio):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### concatenating video1 and video2

```
ffmpeg -i "video1.mp4" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts
ffmpeg -i "video2.mp4" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2.ts
ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "video_combined.mp4"

ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.2.0/include/openjpeg-2.2 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 143 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 800x800, 18 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mpegts, to 'intermediate1.ts':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 800x800, q=2-31, 18 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 12800 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  151 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     135kB time=00:00:05.92 bitrate= 187.5kbits/s speed=2.43e+03x
video:14kB audio:87kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 34.259724%
ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.2.0/include/openjpeg-2.2 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:07.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 157 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 800x800, 15 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mpegts, to 'intermediate2.ts':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 800x800, q=2-31, 15 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 12800 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  195 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     192kB time=00:00:07.68 bitrate= 204.8kbits/s speed=2.6e+03x
video:14kB audio:129kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 33.605099%
ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.2.0/include/openjpeg-2.2 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:07.82, start: 1.456778, bitrate: 342 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 800x800, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](und): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 169 kb/s
Output #0, mp4, to 'video_combined.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(progressive), 800x800, q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 169 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  346 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     257kB time=00:00:13.74 bitrate= 153.3kbits/s speed=1.54e+03x
video:30kB audio:217kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:1kB muxing overhead: 4.243830%
```

The output of the combined video contains the extra silences, but the second audio doesn't combine properly:

[image]

### Method 2: Create combined video directly

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -map 0 \
    -vcodec libx264 \
    -aprofile aac_low -acodec aac -strict experimental -cutoff 15000 -b:a 32k 
    "video_combined.mp4"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand “durations are not synced with the audio”. Can you show the full ffmpeg output from these commands?

Comment: @slhck I added the output and some images to make it clear. What I mean is that I get more video duration than would be necessary given the duration of the audio, and on top of that when I combine both mp4s, the second audio doesn't start when the second image first appears